# One Java Project with multiple Git repos

Tags: spring, git, maven

We have one big java web-project, and we are using Git locally, and we have Stash as an in-house Git Server to commit/push our code to.

The following are all separate repo's in our git:

```
repo - java/spring/maven/hibernate entity and dao's jar
repo - java/spring/maven - business services 1 which makes use of the previous jar
repo - java/spring/maven - business services 2 which makes use of the previous jar
repo - java/spring/maven - business services 3 which makes use of the previous jar
repo - java/spring/maven/smartgwt - business services 2 which makes use of the previous 3 business service jars.
```

All of these build separately with their own maven pom.xml file.  In this architecture, when we add a new DAO method, we put a similar Business Service call in, 
and then we add a web-service GET to handle a call to that new business service.

One of my colleagues doesn't like git and finds it too much work to manage these separate repos, for that reason and many others, he would prefer to go back to svn.
He also thinks branching will become too much work for each repo.  I personally think it would be crazy to go back to svn, and I think sub-modules might be a better way to go.

Would a better solution be to:

```
repo - Project_BackEnd, which contains 3 or more sub-modules
submodule- java/spring/maven - business services 1 which makes use of the previous jar
submodule- java/spring/maven - business services 2 which makes use of the previous jar
submodule- java/spring/maven - business services 3 which makes use of the previous jar

repo - Project_FrontEnd
submodule - java/spring/maven/smartgwt - business services 2 which makes use of the previous 3 business service jars.
```

I did take a look for a specific example of Git with multiple java Spring projects, but didn't find anything.  I apologize if this is a duplicate of other questions.

UPDATE:
Although I do not mind separate git repos for different aspects of one overall project, my co-workers who are no more git experts than I, find it cumbersome and don't see the overall future benefits of git and I don't want us to go backwards to SVN.

I've done a lot of research between sub-modules and sub-trees, and I don't know if any of these would suit our needs, and I understand they have their pros/cons.

It might be easier to just create git-repo for the backend.  Since we are using maven, we could have a parent maven project, and then create maven modules.  That way the various back-end libraries would have their own pom.xml files and still build different jars.

Any change to any of these sub-modules would then trigger a change, and the CI could do a build on that project.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get your problem. Dependencies should be handled by Maven so it doesn't really matter how you structure the code in your VCS.

Submodules have their own problems and many people try to avoid them. In particular the submodule is bound to a specific commit (in contrast to SVN externals), you you will need to frequently update your submodules.

So either:

- use an IDE that can pull / push multiple repos at once like IntelliJ.
- combine multiple repos in one Git repo with a (Maven) parent POM and multiple modules. The major drawback with this is, that your CI system won't really know which particular module has been updated and might need to build the whole repo when you would only need to rebuild one module.

Comment: This is not a problem with dependencies, and you are correct, mavben handles this.  The problem IS that I broke the various libraries into independent projects.  The first project is a library in that it creates a JAR.  The CI (Jenkins) recognizes changes, and works great.  The second project is setup as another independent repository to create a library JAR to handle business services.  The same with the third repo.   ALL of these are part of one project, just broken down into multiple smaller repos to handle the different aspects of this one overall project.

Comment: Even after updating the question, my answer applies IMHO: Either use an IDE which handles multiple repos as if they are one (IntelliJ for example) or use a parent POM to keep everything together (drawback noted in the answer)

Comment: In our case, the drawback is not a drawback.  if anything in the multi-modules is changes, then we do not mind that entire project being built.   As a matter of fact, that's the way we'd prefer it.

Comment: Ok, then one Git repo with a parent and three modules it is, right?

Comment: Yep.  I think that is the best way to go since this one whole section is all going to be version-ed together anyway.

Comment: Great, if that's the right approach, please accept it as the answer